# "Visualized" equivalent adjective for audio

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy, sense-verbs

Are there such words as "audiolized" or "audibilized"?

**EDIT:** Merriam-Webster has the word [Audibilized](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audibilized) indexed with no definition! <strike>What I was trying to achieve was to say that `something is an audibilized presentation of some other thing`, exactly the same way we use `visualized presentation`.</strike>

**EDIT:** [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUqFelc84XE) is a visualization of a sort algorithm. Therefore [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8g-iYGHpEA) is ...? Audilization? Auralization? Sound representation?

**EDIT:** [This one](http://wheelof.com/whitney/whitneyCarol.swf) as well.

Comment: I have a number of musician friends and I have never heard any of them use these words. However, I often hear visual artists and photographers use 'visualized'.

Comment: Funny - I had the same thought, typed "the audible eqivalent of visualize" and came across this page. Remarkable to know others are having the same obscure thoughts as you - gotta love google!! I vote for "audiolize". It's the easiest to say, the most mellifluous (like that word). I'm a guitarist and was looking for a word to describe what i do when improvising - sometimes it's a visual process when i think in terms of scale intervals on the fretboard, sometimes it's "auralizing" when i imagine how the notes will sound before i play them. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just based on the comparable stem, I would expect the term to be to '[auralize](http://www.google.com/search?q=auralize)'.  I suppose the same can be said for 'audibiilze', although 'audiolize' would only seem comparable if the visual word was 'videolize'.

Comment: I like this. I have a difficult time auralizing audiolized or audibilized.

Comment: Sorry for necro-threading - I have a twitter search for "auralization" that linked to this question today (see http://bit.ly/1kd9qQQ).  There  is precedent for using the word auralize, in the field of aircraft noise simulation, eg: http://bit.ly/1tUKa8Q and similar academic papers.

Answer (score 9):

In the music education community, we often say "audiate" when referring to hearing a melody in "the mind's ear".

The term was coined by music education guru Edwin Gordon, and I think it's pretty well-known amongst musicians (in addition to music *teachers*).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audiation

Comment: When I read the first bit of this answer to my wife (who is a linguist) she replied with "I didn't know a sentence could fill me with such pure unadulterated joy". Good job sir.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the poster who suggested **audiation**, as that is the process of imagining sound.

In response to your second edit, there is another very appropriate and widely accepted word for representing information with sound: **sonification**.

Comment: At the bottom and not very recognized, but "sonification" is actually the correct answer! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonification

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good single word for this. "Auralise"(/ze) is the most natural, and even that would give most people a double-take before they understood it.

I think it'd be best to rephrase slightly, such as

> X is a presentation of Y in audio form
>   X is an auditory illustration of Y

Answer (score 1):

It appears that both ["audibilized"](http://www.google.com/search?q=audibilized) and ["audiolized"](http://www.google.com/search?q=audiolized) are being used, if only sparingly. Personally, I have never encountered either before (but I think everyone would understand them, thanks to the obvious parallel to the widely used *visualized*).

Comment: If someone said "audibilized" I would have thought that involved the level of sound.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't really make sense,

> What I was trying to achieve was to
>   say that something is an audibilized
>   presentation of some other thing,
>   exactly the same way we use visualized
>   presentation.

Hmm? Usually one would say "a visualization". I'm not sure what "visualized presentation" is meant to be. A visualization of data etc.

There are some suggestions as answers here, frankly I think they are dubious. If you want to say this in English, "represent in sound" as a verb and "representation in sound" or "sound representation" would be OK.

Comment: I was going to say basically the same. I've never heard ""visualized presentation" and the example didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a word that many or all of your audience will understand, why not try "imagine"?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest audible, sonic , or simply audio. I realize these lack the 'made into' suffix, but I think your listeners will stumble less over these than auralize or audibilized. To me audibilized suggests that some imperceptible sound was amplified to the point of audibility, rather than translated from another sensory modality.