# If ‘pronunciation’ pairs with ‘sound’, which word should ‘spelling’ pair with?

Tags: word-choice, analogy, pronunciation-vs-spelling

If *pronunciation* pairs with *sound*, which word should *spelling* pair with?

Comment: Somehow I feel reminded of [“Visualized” equivalent adjective for audio](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/), except it's the other way round this time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a couple of implied analogies here:

A word’s **pronunciation** is how it **sounds**, so a word’s **spelling** is how it ___.

- **looks**
- **appears**

A word’s **pronunciation** is what **sound** it makes when used, so a word’s **spelling** is what ___ it makes when used.

- **shape**
- **appearance**
- **visual manifestation**

Comment: +1, I think that "look" is actually the best candidate, because just as "sound", it works *both* as a verb and as a noun (as opposed to the other candidates on your list and elsewhere on this page).

Comment: Actually, the word that the OP is looking for might be *orthography*.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I said "sight" earlier but that's not right. (In that case you'd have said "hearing" not "sound"). Maybe "vision"?