# How do I call a word for audible equivalent of visualize?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

I was looking for a word that would convey a similar meaning for "audio" as it is for "visualize." I ran into several suggestions, but as a former musician, I personally prefer the word - "audiate" from "audiation." However, when checked in google, the Wiktionary describes it as a sound that one hears without that sound physically present there.

It is funny that there is no word in English to describe it adequately, and even Google does not register such.

Comment: John said "Imagine a forest on a hillside." He visualised the scene. John continued "There are birds singing..." He **heard** the sounds **in his mind**.

Comment: However, we do use visualization tools as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Visualized" equivalent adjective for audio](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/visualized-equivalent-adjective-for-audio)

Comment: Obviously, "audioears".

Comment: Doesn't the definition you've quoted for *audiate* demonstrate that it *is* the right word? It is usually used in a musical context, but I don't think that prevents its use in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use 'compose', the meaning of which is usually to write out and arrange for performance, but also includes doing the mental labor of putting together sounds:

From wiktionary: 4. (transitive or intransitive) To construct by mental labor; to think up; particularly, to produce or create a literary or musical work.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compose

Comment: As your quote shows, *compose* isn't specific to sound, which the question seems to want.

Answer (score 0):

**Auralize** and **auralization** are in common use. There’s a Wikipedia entry at  https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/auralize

I recall this term being used at conferences like ACM Siggraph as the audio counterpart to visual rendering of data (which includes the animation data used in games and movies.

Here’s an academic reference from 2002: [https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~funk/course02.pdf](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Efunk/course02.pdf)

Comment: I accept that these are valid (cromulent?) words but "in common use" is a bit of an exaggeration, especially when compared with visualize/visualise and visualization/visualisation. Personally I prefer "audiate" and "audiation". However all four words are pretty obscure, I'd never heard any of them.